# Looking for a query that only returns results with matching IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

sorry in advance for beeing stupid :)

I have the following tables
[image: tables]

I want to search for different values ​​and then get a group_id back that contains all the values ​​I'm looking for. Is that possible, or does the structure have to be changed for this?

Comment: You could INTERSECT queries, or use multiple AND statements, or a variety of other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example if you only need to select group_id for which value A, B and C all are available you can use group by with aggregation like below:

```
SELECT group_id FROM envelope_characteristic
WHERE value IN ('A','B','C');
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE)=3
```

Comment: You are most welcome @Ben76137. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell your existing structure should be OK.
You could write a query that goes like this:

```
SELECT group_id FROM envelope_characteristic WHERE value IN (...);
```

It'll return all the group_ids that contain the values you're searching for.